# PHPから送信するメールの文字化け【半角カナ 依存文字】を改善したい

Tags: php

PHPで作成した問い合わせフォームより指定アドレスに送信されるメールの、半角カナと依存記号が
？と文字化けをしてしまいます。
お力添えいただけないでしょうか。
（素人ながら色々試してみたのですが、解決できなく質問させていただきました。）

ど素人なので、詳しく教えていただけると大変助かります。

現時点のコードです↓

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="ja" xml:lang="ja" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>お問い合わせフォーム</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>


</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0">
<p align="center"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/toiawase_01.jpg" width="800" height="48" border="0"></a></p>
<table width="800" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>

    <th height="64" scope="col"><div align="left">
      <?php
  // お問い合わせ内容
  $title5 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title5'],
  ENT_QUOTES);
  // お名前
  $title1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title1'],
  ENT_QUOTES);
  // 会社名
  $title2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title2'],
  ENT_QUOTES);
  // お電話番号
  $title3 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title3'],
  ENT_QUOTES);
  // メールアドレス
  $title4 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title4'],
  ENT_QUOTES);


  // 日本語(SJIS)の指定
  mb_language('ja');
  mb_internal_encoding('SJIS');

  // Fromアドレスの設定(自動送信<送信元のアドレス>)
  $name = '自動送信';
  $email = '<送信元のアドレス>';
  $header = 'Form: '. mb_encode_mimeheader($name) . '<' . $email .'>';

  // 本文の末尾に[お名前][ふりがな][お電話番号][メールアドレス]を追加
  $title5 = $title5 . "\n[ 名　　　　　前 : " . $title1. "

  会　　社　　名 : " . $title2. "

  電  話  番  号 : " . $title3. "

  メールアドレス : " . $title4. "]";


  // メール送信
  $result = mb_send_mail("<ﾒｰﾙｱﾄﾞﾚｽ>",'問い合わせがきました',$title5,$header);

  //メール送信の確認
  if ($result){
      // メール送信の成功
      echo '■お問い合わせ内容を担当者へ送信しました。';
  } else {
      // メール送信の失敗
      echo '■担当者への送信に失敗しました。 ';
  }
?>
    </div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div align="center"><img src="images/ain.jpg" width="800" height="76"></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="c1" style="text-align:left"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 半角カナや機種依存文字を除いた状態では試してみましたか？これらの文字が含まれる場合だけが問題なのか、それとも文字コードの問題なのかは試して切り分けができるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。半角カナや依存文字がなければ全く問題ないのですが、半角カナや依存文字を入れるとその部分のみが？と表示されてしまいます。m(__)m

Comment: この辺が何か参考になれば。[フォームから送った半角カナの文字化け回避](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/175481.html)、[PHPまとめ - 日本語を扱う](http://doremi.s206.xrea.com/php/tips/mbconv.html)、[日々のめも:いわゆる半角ｶﾅの文字化けについて](http://rzl.shiga-saku.net/e535113.html)、[半角カタカナの文字化けについて](http://kenta.jpn.org/bbs/read.php?FID=2&TID=624)

Comment: 日本語のメールは、UTF8もしくは、ISO-2022-JPで送信すると色々な所で、トラブルなく受信できるので、UTF8（ページエンコーディングも含めて）で送信する事をお薦めします。

Comment: 更にこんなのが見つかりました。[ＰＨＰの文字コードを究める](https://ameblo.jp/mingw/entry-10373863820.html)、[PHPでJIS以外の文字を文字化けせずに日本語メールを送る方法](http://tech.aainc.co.jp/archives/3570)、[いわゆる半角カナや種依存文字などをメールで送信する方法](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/t_komura/20091101/1257080705)

Comment: mb_internal_encoding('SJIS');　を　mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');へ　<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis">　を　<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">　に変更してみたのですが、それを行うと今まで読めていた文字すら文字化けしてしまうようになってしまいました。m(__)m

Comment: プロの人が提供している出来合いのフリー版があります。[【MailForm01】PHP多機能メールフォーム　フリー（無料）版](https://www.php-factory.net/mail/01.php)　上記個々のアドバイスを理解して対処する力を養うのも良いですが、こういうものを使って手早く解決する方法もあります。